# How to check my ios developer certificate is expired?

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codesign error: Certificate identity appearing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932522/codesign-error-certificate-identity-appearing-twice)

I am getting this error.

Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer: tobias diestelkamp (PXVT443VS6)' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.

Is it possible that this error occurs because of expired certificate?? I dont know my certificate is expired or not..

Comment: you can find that in keychain. "Expires"

Comment: its Error says you have two provisioning certificate in you key-chain remove older from key-chain and set Proper cod sight in to Bild phase

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932522/codesign-error-certificate-identity-appearing-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are having more than 1 certificate with same name in keychain.
Just delete the old one and keep the new one installed. If it does not fix the problem delete all the certificates of that particular name, install a fresh one and restart the xcode and mac.
I was having the same problem and this procedure helped me.
Hope you will get helped also.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Keychain Access` application (under `Applications > Utilities`), click the `login` keychain on the upper-left, sort by `Name`, then scroll down to `iPhone Developer`. There should be a column `Expires`. Just delete the expired certificate. (Be careful not to delete the key. The key will be automatically selected based on the certificate, and it's sometimes hard to tell which key corresponds to the certificate. But the code signing tools will figure it out.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to keychain access and click on certificate in catogory and in that see that any certificate is display two time,if it is then click on certificate than upper window display all the detail about that certificate. if the certificate detail says "this certificate has been revoked" than delete that certificate.