# codesign throws err 'errSecInternalComponent'

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am getting `errSecInternalComponent` when running the codesign command.
If I go to the keychain and change the certificate to `always trust` and run `codesign` command again, I get `Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Developer ID Application: xxxxxx (xxxxxx)"./workspace/Myapp.app: errSecInternalComponent`

This first time this happened was when I exported the developer certificate from another MacOS and imported it. Then I tried deleting the keychains, recreating it, installing apple root certificates, but still getting the same error.

Finally, I generated a new developer certificate and added it to the keychain, but still not working.

I am not sure what's different about this MAC. It's running Majave now. When the problem first happened it was running High sierra.

Answer (score 4):

There could be many possible reasons for this error. Two frequent issues are:

1. `codesign` tool `does not have access` to the keychain item. Either explicitly give access to codesign or allow all applications to access it.
2. Unlock the keychain: `security unlock-keychain <Full path to keychain>`

Can get the full path using, *security list-keychains*

Answer (score 3):

There were two problems:

1. I had duplicate identities in my keychain, which is the same with this 
   [Duplicate identity after importing single certificate in OSX 10.10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903603/duplicate-identity-after-importing-single-certificate-in-osx-10-10-3)
2. The access permissions for the private key needs to allow codesign or allow all.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly the same issue, but we encountered a errSecInternalComponent during a build on jenkins. Increasing the timeout after which the keychain is closed again fixed it.